# How can I create a new "file type" in the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, registry

To create a registry entry, the `reg` command is used. How can I use the `reg` command to specify a file, for example, of type `.test` to automatically open with openTest.exe, and be listed as a `Useless Test File` under the file type details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this batch to Associate .test as filetype and default run program to run the .test file.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
ASSOC .test=Useless Test File

set myapppath="%homedrive%\MyTestProgram\"
REG ADD "HKCR\.test\DefaultIcon" /d %myapppath%\openTest.ico
REG ADD "HKCR\.test\shell\Open\command" /d "%myapppath%\openTest.exe %%1"
```

The above batch will associate **".test"** and set its description as **"Useless Test File"**

**myapppath** will set your path to your application directory.(edit path as required)

Comment: Why do I need the second line?

Comment: @MazeOfEncryption 

read more about Delayed Expansion

[ss64]https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html